# Añadir una columna en una posición específica del dataframe

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando sobre un dataframe y quiero añadir una nueva columna que muestre el orden de los elementos que tengo en mi base y ponerla en un posición específica, es decir, que no se cree automáticamente al final.

El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:

```
df <- mutate(df, Orden = row_number())
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español! Antes que todo te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por el [tour] y aprovecha y mira como [ask] correctamente. Las preguntas de este tipo, en el que tienes un objetivo y quieres que alguien te la solcuione no son bienvenidas. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y pon lo que has intentado y los problemas que te han surgido

Comment: Revisa los parámetros `.before` y `.after` de `mutate()` que te permiten agregar las nuevas columnas antes de o después de alguna otra. Sino la forma clásica es reordenar la columnas al final con un `select()`

Answer (score 4):

Usando tidyverse te encuentras con varias opciones para ordenar columnas, entre ellas:

1.-En el mismo mutate, dar la instruccion que se genere despues de "Columna_3"

```
df <-mutate(df, Orden = row_number(), .after = Columna_3)
```

2.- Usando relocate, puedes usar los parámetros **.before** y **.after**

```
df <-mutate(df, Orden = row_number()) %>%
  relocate(Orden, .before = Columna_3)

df <-mutate(df, Orden = row_number()) %>%
      relocate(Orden, .after = Columna_3)
```

3.-Usando select

```
df <-mutate(df, Orden = row_number()) %>%
          select(Columna1, Columna2, Orden, everything())
```

Donde: everything() te completara las columnas restantes, si es que no deseas escribirlas todas.

Existen muchas maneras de hacer esto, también podrías investigar mas sobre las funciones:

-contains()

-starts_with()

-ends_with()

Que se suelen usar dentro de select(), las cuales aprendiendo a combinarlas, te brindan mayor facilidad a este tipo de tratamientos.